# Buttons not disabled when initializing component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm using the [disabled] property to decide if button elements should be or not disabled, depending if an array.length returns 0 or not.

This is working fine after the user interacts with the component, however the buttons aren't disabled when the component is initialized and the array is empty.

typescript

```
constructor() {
    this.macrosSelected = [];
  }
```

html

```
<button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-secondary"
          [disabled]="!macrosSelected.length"
>
```

As I said, this code is enabling the button when the array has an object inside it, and disabling it once the array returns to an empty state.

Comment: I am not sure if that fixes the problem, but I would advice you to initialise your data on `ngOnInit` instead of constructor

Comment: Are you sure your console does not have any errors? maybe `macrosSelected` is `null` at the beginning. You could use `[disabled]="!macrosSelected?.length"`

Comment: @StPaulis I have tried that before, as well as initialise the array when I declare the variable

Comment: Can you share a stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

As you have assigned `macrosSelected = []` in your constructor then this will be the initial value of your variable. If you are assigning this variable using `@Input()` decorator or by a service, those will update this variable after the constructor call means second assignment. So you can simply check the length of `macrosSelected` variable like below.

Your template code must be like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" [disabled]="macrosSelected.length === 0"></button>
```